# RackUnit source location inside of macros

Tags: macros, racket, rackunit

I am building a set of rackunit tests, where the actual [`test-case`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=test-case#%28form._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._test-case%29%29) and [`check-equal?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=check-equal%3F#%28def._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._check-equal~3f%29%29) function is defined in a macro. The code looks something like this:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit
         rackunit/text-ui)

(define-syntax (my-test=? stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ case1 case2)
     (syntax/loc stx
       (test-case "tests"
         (check-equal? case1 case2)))]))

(define tests
  (test-suite "tests"
    (my-test=? 'a 'b)))

(run-tests tests)
```

However, when I run this code I get the following output:

```
--------------------
tests > tests
tests
FAILURE
name:       check-equal?
location:   unsaved-editor:11:9
actual:     'a
expected:   'b
. Check failure
--------------------
0 success(es) 1 failure(s) 0 error(s) 1 test(s) run
```

Where line 11 is the line of the `check-equal?` function inside of the macro: `(check-equal? case1 case2)))]))`

Is there any way I can rackunit to show the error on the line where `my-test=?` is used: `(my-test=? 'a 'b)))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the syntax location directly on the `check-equal?` expression to get the behavior that you want. Here's an example:

```
(define-syntax (my-test=? stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ case1 case2)
     (quasisyntax
       (test-case "tests"
         #,(syntax/loc stx (check-equal? case1 case2))))]))
```

Putting the syntax location on the outer expression doesn't automatically propagate it in general.

With this change, the location is reported as "15:4" for me (as opposed to "11:9") which is where the `(my-test=? 'a 'b)` expression occurs.

Comment: Yes, this [has tripped me up before](http://www.greghendershott.com/2014/01/using-syntax-loc.html). It turns out the phrase "immediate syntax object" in the documentation is significant!